# filter list of items when clicking category link

Tags: angularjs

I have  a list of items with "ng-repeat". Each item contains a div with a link title and link category. When clicking on a category, I want to filter the list of items, so that it only shows the items belonging to that category. how can I achieve that?

So far I have a list of items:

```
  <div class="link_line" ng-repeat="link in links | filter: ? ">
    <div class="title"><a href="{{link.url}}" target="_blank">{{link.title}}</a></div>
    <div class="category_label" ng-click="filterCategory(link)>{{ link.category }}</div>
  </div>
```

And in the controller I have a function "filterCategory" which shows an alert with the link category. And I have the "filter: ?" where I guess the value of the filter has to come. Ths is the controller function:

```
  $scope.filterCategory = (link) ->
    alert(link.category)
```

Any idea how to proceed? Thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can create an object on your controller's scope intended for filtering and pass it to the `filter` expression in `ng-repeat`

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('main', function($scope) {
    $scope.filters = { };

    $scope.links = [
        {name: 'Apple', category: 'Fruit'},
        {name: 'Pear', category: 'Fruit'},
        {name: 'Almond', category: 'Nut'},
        {name: 'Mango', category: 'Fruit'},
        {name: 'Cashew', category: 'Nut'}
    ];
});
```

So now we have a `filters` object attached to the scope. If it gets a key of `category`, the `filter` expression will automatically filter the objects according to whether or not they have a key of `category` and it matches.

For more details, look at the "Parameters" section of the [filter docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter).

So your HTML could look like:

```
<div class="link_line" ng-repeat="link in links | filter:filters">
    <div class="title"><a href="{{link.url}}" target="_blank">{{link.title}}</a></div>
    <div class="category_label" ng-click="filters.category = link.category">{{ link.category }}</div>
</div>
```

[Here's a quick fiddle of this in action](http://jsfiddle.net/cKa6K/).

Comment: I needed something similar and your answer helped me a lot! I had to change it so it supports multiple categories per item, this is what I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/xffe9zwp/

Comment: If $scope.links have int value, how can i filter values in between ? eg: "5>= && 10<="

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular.module('app',[])
  .controller('MainController', function($scope) { 
  $scope.team =[
    {cat_id:1,team: 'alpha'},
    {cat_id:2,team: 'beta'},
    {cat_id:3,team: 'gamma'}
               ];
  
    $scope.players = [
      {name: 'Gene',cat_id : 1},
      {name: 'George',cat_id : 2},
      {name: 'Steve',cat_id : 3},
      {name: 'Pzula',cat_id : 2},
      {name: 'shrikant',cat_id : 3}
    ];
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController"> 
    
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in team ">
{{value.team}}
  
 <li ng-repeat="p in players " ng-if="p.cat_id==value.cat_id">
   {{ p.name }}
 </li>
  
</ul>
</div>
```