# angularjs ng-repeat filter based on array values on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array `$scope.something = ['xyz','abc','pqr'];`

On click, I want to filter the `ng-repeat` data so that it will return the resulting JSON data filtered with `'xyz'`, `'pqr'`, and `'abc'`.

`ng-repeat="data in flt_det | filter:something"`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882370/filter-list-of-items-when-clicking-category-link)

Comment: no this is some other scenario. the click is on a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to filter data with any of the matching elements inside `$scope.something` then you may need to craete a custom filter:

```
app.filter("somethingFilter", function() {
   return function(array, something) {
     return array.filter(function(ele) {
          return (something.indexOf(ele) > 0)
      });
   }
});
```

Now in your HTML,

```
ng-repeat="data in flt_det | filter:something".
```

This will filter `flt_det` if the data is present in `something` array.

> ON click of a button?

```
$scope.buttonClickHandler = function() {
     $scope.flt_det = $scope.flt_det.filter(function(ele) {
                               return ($scope.something.indexOf(ele) > 0)
                        });
}
```

This will update the `$scope.flt_det` data on click of the button.

You can even use `$filter` in this case as well:

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $filter)
{
    $scope.buttonClickHandler = function() {
        $scope.flt_det = $filter('somethingFilter')($scope.flt_det,$scope.something);
    };
});
```

> EDIT DEMO

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
 $scope.flt_det = ["abc", "pqr", "sdfs", "sdfds", "xyz"];
 $scope.something = ["abc", "pqr", "xyz"];
 $scope.buttonClickHandler = function() {
  $scope.flt_det = $scope.flt_det.filter(function(ele) {
        return ($scope.something.indexOf(ele) > 0)
     });
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="data in flt_det">
   {{data}}
</div>
<button type="button" ng-click="buttonClickHandler()">Filter data</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i need the result based on the 3 value and can we do this operation on click of a single button ?

Comment: Updated with buttonClick handler.

Comment: Added a demo as well :) @user2131395

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Fixed to address question of filtering using the array input

Another option if you want to use the built-in Angular filters within your controller instead of a custom filter, is to do something like this (working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4n9a0rLg/1/)):

```
$scope.filtered = [];
    for(var index = 0; index < $scope.something.length; index++) {
      var singleFilter = $filter('filter')($scope.flt_det, $scope.something[index]);
      $scope.filtered = _.union($scope.filtered, singleFilter);
    }
```

This maintains a separate $scope.filtered array. It also utilizes Underscore.js's union function. Then your html will look like this:

```
ng-repeat="data in filtered"
```

See the Angular documentation here for using a filter in the controller: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: The OP wants to use `$scope.something` array to filter another array `$scope.flt_det`. But $filter will filter the first argument `array` with a primitive value which is second argument.

Comment: Thanks @mohamedrias, definitely misunderstood the question. Fixed the answer