# Filter ng-repeat on ng-click using dynamic data

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

My html

```
<span ng-repeat="types in type" ng-click="itemClicked($index)">
    <i class="mdi {{types.logo}} s24" ng-class="{ 'active': $index == selectedIndex }">
    <md-tooltip>{{types.name}}</md-tooltip>
    </i>
</span>
<md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="assets in data">
   <img ng-src="{{assets.image}}" class="md-avatar" alt="{{item.who}}" />
   <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
   <h3>{{assets.name}} {{assets.code}}</h3>
   <h4>{{assets.location}}, {{assets.price}}, $1000</h4>
   <p>{{assets.weeksbooked.weeks}}</p>
   </div>
   <md-divider ></md-divider>
</md-list-item>
```

if i click on i element i want to show the results only with the clicked type means i have a field 'type' in my dataset(assets).
                                           Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: can you post your filter code you have so far?

Comment: $scope.getResult = function(a){

            return item.type == a;
               

        }    @Rhumborl

Comment: a is the parameter which i passed on ng-clik.  @Rhumborl

Comment: Got the solution from here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882370/filter-list-of-items-when-clicking-category-link