# AngularJS Filter By Category

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to display menu by category. The name of each category is the name of the key of an array of menu items, such as "brownies", "cakes."

This is what I am referencing, but something seems to be off:

[filter list of items when clicking category link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882370/filter-list-of-items-when-clicking-category-link)

html:

```
<section class="choices">
  <div class="categories">
   <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="menu in fullMenu">
      <a ng-repeat="(key,val) in menu" href="" ng-click="categoryFilters.category = {{key}}">{{key}}
      </a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>

</section>

<section class="category" ng-repeat="menu in fullMenu | filter: categoryFilters">

  <div ng-repeat="items in menu">
   <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      <img src="{{item.image_url}}">
      <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
      <p>{{item.description}}</p>
      <p><span>$</span>{{item.price}}</p>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>

</section>
```

JS:

```
  angular.module('bakeryMenuApp')
  .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {  
    dataService.getMenus(function(response) { 
        $scope.fullMenu = response.data.menus;
        $scope.categoryFilters = {}   
    });
  })
```

JSON:

```
{  
   "menus":[  
      {  
         "brownies":[  
            {  
               "name":"Baker's Choice Bars Assortment",
               "price":"45",
               "description":"A beautiful and delicious assortment of Magnolia Bakery’s double fudge brownies, chocolate chunk blondies and magic cookie bars.",
               "image_url":"https://pantograph0.goldbely.com/s364/uploads/product_image/image/8346/bakers-choice-bars-assortment.1ddd25a1f59a89a1de2d0583dab50000.jpg",
               "is_vegan":false,
               "is_gluten_free":false
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "cakes":[  
            {  
               "name":"Raseberry Lemon Cake",
               "price":"50",
               "description":"Vanilla crème fraîche cake layered with raspberry Swiss meringue buttercream and lemon curd filling, covered with raspberry buttercream.",
               "image_url":"http://www.empirecake.com/_main_site/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Rasberry_Lemon_01_final_drkr-600.jpg",
               "is_vegan":false,
               "is_gluten_free":false
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Please post JSON response too.

Comment: Please paste your JSON  also

Comment: added JSON @hva.narola

Comment: added JSON @gayathri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve it by checking the condition in a proper way

**Controller** && **HTML**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
$scope.category = '';
  $scope.categoryList = function(value) {
    $scope.category = value;
  }
  $scope.menus = [{
    "brownies": [{
      "name": "Baker's Choice Bars Assortment",
      "price": "45",
      "description": "A beautiful and delicious assortment of Magnolia Bakery’s double fudge brownies, chocolate chunk blondies and magic cookie bars.",
      "image_url": "https://pantograph0.goldbely.com/s364/uploads/product_image/image/8346/bakers-choice-bars-assortment.1ddd25a1f59a89a1de2d0583dab50000.jpg",
      "is_vegan": false,
      "is_gluten_free": false
    }]
  }, {
    "cakes": [{
      "name": "Raseberry Lemon Cake",
      "price": "50",
      "description": "Vanilla crème fraîche cake layered with raspberry Swiss meringue buttercream and lemon curd filling, covered with raspberry buttercream.",
      "image_url": "http://www.empirecake.com/_main_site/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Rasberry_Lemon_01_final_drkr-600.jpg",
      "is_vegan": false,
      "is_gluten_free": false
    }]
  }]
});
```

```css
form.ng-pristine {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

form.ng-dirty {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <section class="choices">
    <div class="categories">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="menu in menus">
          <a ng-repeat="(key,val) in menu" href="" ng-click="categoryList(key)">{{key}}
      </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </section>
  <section class="category" ng-repeat="menu in menus">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, items) in menu">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-show="category == key">
          <div>
            <img src="{{item.image_url}}">
            <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
            <p>{{item.description}}</p>
            <p><span>$</span>{{item.price}}</p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Nice! Could you explain it a little?

Comment: @JaeeunLee I have added `ng-show` to `li` and it check whether the variable `category` is equal to the key and it will show the respected `li`. The click event is added to `a` to set the clicked variable to `category` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should use custom filter to filter by object key and use a function to set category by click.

can try like this

**Html**:

```
<section class="choices">
    <div class="categories">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="menu in fullMenu">
          <a ng-repeat="(key,val) in menu" href="" ng-click="setFilterCategory(key)">{{key}}
      </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="category" ng-repeat="menu in fullMenu | filter: filterByCategory">
    <div ng-repeat="items in menu">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
          <img src="{{item.image_url}}">
          <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
          <p>{{item.description}}</p>
          <p>
            <span>$</span> {{item.price}}

          </p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
```

and **controller**:

```
  $scope.selectedCategory = '';

  $scope.setFilterCategory = function(value) {
    $scope.selectedCategory = value;
  };

  $scope.filterByCategory = function(item) {
    if ($scope.selectedCategory)
      return $scope.selectedCategory === Object.keys(item)[0];
    else
      return item;
  };
```

**[PLUNKER DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/G8Ouc3j1v55I2cVdvnuE?p=preview)**